# Different Values for node coordinate in scripting/ probe value and .INP file

Tags: python, coordinates, nodes, abaqus

I receive different x,y,z values as the coordinate for my node from my codes and other ways (the numbers are real close though).

Here is my script:

```html
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from caeModules import *
from driverUtils import executeOnCaeStartup
import odbAccess

odb = session.odbs['C:/Users/AP31140/Documents/Work Directory/Implicit/Job-newnew1.odb']
node_coordinates = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].nodes[116550].coordinates
```

The result of my script is the following picture:[Coords from scripting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onZCP.jpg)

However I have checked these values in 2 other ways as well but they don't add up with the result from my codes.(the other two ways match with each other though).

One from Probe values : [Probe values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mplRG.jpg)

And another one from abaqus .INP file: [.INP file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A21uQ.jpg)

I really need that I have these values with my script since it is way easier to deal with for my next approach.

Comment: Make sure your code is accessing the correct node. The value you use for accessing a node inside `odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].nodes` is a list index, not a node label. It is possible that a node at index 116550 is not a node with a label 116550. Print the label to see if you are looking at the correct node.

Comment: Thank you so much @hgazibara. Yes you were right. I changed it to `node_coordinates = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1'].nodes[116550-1].coordinates` and it showed me the correct node coordinate which matches with the data from Probe Values and .INP file.

Many thanks.